# ASP.NET Page_Load is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, pageload, page-init

I created a 2D array `Board`, holding objects of `GameCell`.

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>ארבע בשורה</h1>
        <div id="Board">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="MyBoard" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Game.CreateControls();
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        Game.Set(MyBoard, Label1);
        Game.Reset();
    }
}
```

**GameCell.cs:**

```
public class GameCell : ImageButton
{
    public Position Position; // Justs holds the properties of Row and Col
    public CellType Type;

    public GameCell(Position Pos)
    {
        this.Position = new Position(Pos);
        this.Type = CellType.Empty;
    }
}
```

**Game.cs:**

```
public class Game
{
    public const int R = 6;
    public const int C = 9;

    public static GameCell[,] Board;
    public static PlaceHolder Holder;
    public static Label Log;

    public static CellType CurrentType;

    public static string[] Images = new string[] { "red", "empty", "blue" };

    public static void Set(PlaceHolder Holder, Label Log)
    {
        Game.Reset();
        Game.Holder = Holder;
        Game.Log = Log;
    }

    public static void CreateControls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Game.R; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Game.C; j++)
            {
                Game.Board[i, j].ImageUrl = Game.ImageUrlByType(Game.Board[i, j].Type);
                Game.Board[i, j].ID = i + "_" + j;
                Game.Board[i, j].Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(Image_Click);

                Game.Holder.Controls.Add(Game.Board[i, j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = 0;
        int col = int.Parse(((GameCell)sender).ID[2].ToString());

        if (Game.Board[row, col].Type == CellType.Empty)
        {
            while (row < Game.R - 1 && Game.Board[row, col].Type == CellType.Empty)
            {
                row++;
            }

            Game.SetImage(row, col);
            Game.CurrentType = (CellType)(-(int)Game.CurrentType);
            Log.Text = col + " " + row + " " + Game.CurrentType;

            Game.Board[row, col].Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    public static void SetImage(int r, int c)
    {
        Game.Board[r, c].Type = Game.CurrentType;
        Game.Board[r, c].ImageUrl = Game.ImageUrlByType(Game.CurrentType);
    }

    public static void Reset()
    {
        Game.Board = new GameCell[R, C];
        Game.CurrentType = CellType.Blue;

        for (int i = 0; i < Game.R; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Game.C; j++)
            {
                Game.Board[i, j] = new GameCell(new Position(i, j));
            }
        }
    }

    public static string ImageUrlByType(CellType t)
    {
        return "includes/images/" + Game.Images[(int)t + 1] + ".png";
    }
}
```

The controls are rendered, and are clickable when first launching the project, but after I do click one of them, no controls are added to my Holder (`MyBoard`).

Why is this happening?

**Edit:**

I found the solution. passing `MyBoard` as an argument to `CreateControls` did it. Maybe the reference wasn't reliable anymore (I saved it in an object) after page_load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your `Page_Load` is called, you recreate your controls. They are stored in static members, which means that all users of this web site share a common board. Is this really what you want? Would it not be better to store the Game in the Session? (of course I don't know your requirements, but I always try to avoid static members in web applications).

A possible solution could be to check whether it is not a postback, before you recreate the controls.

```
if (!IsPostback)
{

}
```

Comment: My first try was an instance of Game (with non-static members), but it failed, so I thought static members would help.

Comment: Agreed. Static members (fields and properties) in a web application are a bad idea. The  data will be shared across threads with unpredictable results. (Static methods are fine.)

Comment: Instance members are lost after the request, static members are shared between all users and accessed by multiple threads possibly at the same time. You could store your Game in a Session variable instead, then every user has it's own game and you don't have multithreading problems.